# :disable selector not working in Jquery Validate ignore clause

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have multiple AJAX populated dropdown lists on an HTML page. The form is validated using JQuery Validate.

I have set the dropdown lists to 'disabled' until the AJAX has completed, at which point the disabled property is removed.

The contents of these fields are mandatory. I would like to validate them even if they are disabled to prevent the user submitting a form that is still loading mandatory AJAX data.

My HTML is:

```
<form id="myform">
  <select name="foo" id="foo" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="1">Option1</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <select name="bar" id="bar">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="1">Option1</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

I am using the following ignore parameter in JQuery Validate as suggested in the comments below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myform').validate({
    ignore:[],
        rules: {
            foo: {
                required: true
            },
            bar: {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The Validate script still does not appear to be ignoring the disabled status of the field. What am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/aekntmor/

I have tried adding a class to the disabled  dropdown list and then modifying the script as such.

```
<select name="foo" id="foo" class="validate-disabled" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="1">Option1</option>
 </select>
```

```
ignore: ':disabled:not(.validate-disabled)',
```

Comment: I think you might not fully understand what `ignore` means.  In this context, it means "do not validate".  Your jsFiddle is working exactly like it is supposed to work.  You have set the plugin to "ignore" the disabled field.  I click the submit button and the disabled field is ignored... it is not validated.  Please fix your question.  You should also have the demo code in the posting as well as the jsFiddle which may not exist someday.

Comment: If you want to validate a disabled field, then you must over-ride the `ignore` with something that makes more sense, like "ignore nothing", which looks like `ignore: []`.  If validating everything is too much, then you must write a custom selector that ignores certain hidden/disabled elements and not others.

Comment: Ah! I see. I was under the impression that the 'ignore' ignored the default exclusions. (e.g. hidden, disabled, image etc)
However, I have been attempting to modify the fiddle in order to get this working and have been unable to get the validate to allow input through a disabled field even with  ignore: [].

Comment: I have updated the fiddle and posted the code as requested but can still not get a disabled field to go through any validation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I looked at the source code.  Disabled fields are specifically excluded from being validated, period.  One workaround might be to save the value of the select in a `hidden` field (you can validate those using `ignore` as attempted previously) and then using a conditional inside the `errorPlacement` callback, move the message for the hidden field so that it's next to the disabled `select`.

Comment: I looked at the source code as well and changed it to remove the default `:disabled` reference but that had no effect. I will try your idea. I have generic code setup for dealing with hidden fields and highlighting etc anyway. I am now curious as to what else is causing the block in validation, even when `:disabled` is removed from the codeline.

Comment: Editing the source code of the package is about the worst thing you can do.  It's now a one-off that will break whenever you need to update the version.  It's also no longer considered "the jQuery Validate plugin" and other people coming here for help may not get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done using this plugin.

I am not sure the approach of validating disabled elements is a good idea or makes for a good UX (user experience), and disabled elements were specifically excluded by the developer.

Looking at the source code of [version 1.19.3 of the jQuery Validate plugin](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.3/dist/jquery.validate.js), one can see that any disabled element will not be considered for validation:

```
elements: function() {
    ...
    return $( this.currentForm )
    .find( ... )
    .not( "... :disabled" ) ....
```